# How to get user data now with restrictions on instagram platform api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

There have been lots of changes to the facebook api recently, which now includes the instagram api as well. https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/

They have shutdown a lot of endpoints way ahead of schedule and has created a huge problem for my application which integrates instagram user data. They have the instagram graph api now, but looks like it can be used only for business accounts (looked like that prima facie). Reading through the news past couple of days, I am really confused about what is available and what is not. My application used to get user data (number of followers, recent posts, reach, likes, etc) using the instagram handle provided by users. Since this is totally restricted on the platform api now, is there a way I can have the same functionality using the new graph api? Or should I look into 3rd party APIs? I am open to asking users for authentication (I already have the facility). Can the user information be fetched after they authenticate my app to do so?

Comment: You can still get basic information about the logged in user (follows, followers, number of photos) via `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self` and recent media via `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent`

Comment: @hermanschutte Yeah. Thanks. I think that's the only way out for now. Implemented this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Graph API to get all the details for any IG business account.

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/business-discovery